# Save Command-Prompt Results to a textfile

Tags: ruby, command-line, web-crawler

I'm using the Ruby Gem 'Rawler' to document any broken links on a large website.

The script is meant to be used by non-technical users, on a windows machine. So I have put the command to run Rawler in a .bat file, so users can simply double click without opening command-prompt.

```
rawler http://example.com
```

How can I edit the command to have the results recorded in a text-file, which would open with the results once the command is completed?

---

Bonus:

It would be even better if the results only included pages which have an error rather then listing hundreds of pages which have been scanned with no problem.

e.g. "INFO -- 200 - http://example.com/example"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results can be saved to a text file in the same directory by adding '> filename.txt' to the command.

```
rawler http://lambrecipes.ca > results.txt
```

Comment: Adding `notepad results.txt` to the batchfile will display the result.